# How can i pull data from two recordsets into a single html table using a do-while loop

Tags: php, mysql, do-while

I want to combine the data from the two recordset queries below into one html table.

Any help will be appreciated.

Kind regards

```
<?php

    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
        function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
        {
            $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

            $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") 
                            ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) 
                            : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

            switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;    
            case "long":
            case "int":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "double":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "date":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "defined":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
                break;
            }
        return $theValue;
    }
}
//query Recordset1
$maxRows_Recordset1 = 1;
$pageNum_Recordset1 = 0;
$sourceID = $row_Users['sourceID'];


if (isset($_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'])) {
    $pageNum_Recordset1 = $_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'];
}
$startRow_Recordset1 = $pageNum_Recordset1 * $maxRows_Recordset1;

mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM database1 
                        JOIN users USING (userID)
                        JOIN table1 ON table1.myID = table2.myID 
                        JOIN table4 ON table4.alias = table2.product 
                        JOIN table5 USING (table5ID) 
                     WHERE TO_DAYS(added)=TO_DAYS(NOW()) 
                        AND userID = '300' 
                        AND table5ID ='1'";

$query_limit_Recordset1 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_Recordset1, $startRow_Recordset1, $maxRows_Recordset1);
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_limit_Recordset1, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_Recordset1'])) {
    $totalRows_Recordset1 = $_GET['totalRows_Recordset1'];
} else {
    $all_Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1);
    $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($all_Recordset1);
}
$totalPages_Recordset1 = ceil($totalRows_Recordset1/$maxRows_Recordset1)-1;

$queryString_Recordset1 = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $newParams = array();
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        if (stristr($param, "pageNum_Recordset1") == false && 
            stristr($param, "totalRows_Recordset1") == false) {
            array_push($newParams, $param);
        }
    }
    if (count($newParams) != 0) {
        $queryString_Recordset1 = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
    }
}
$queryString_Recordset1 = sprintf("&totalRows_Recordset1=%d%s", $totalRows_Recordset1, $queryString_Recordset1);

//query Recordset2
$maxRows_Recordset2 = 1;
$pageNum_Recordset2 = 0;

if (isset($_GET['pageNum_Recordset2'])) {
    $pageNum_Recordset2 = $_GET['pageNum_Recordset2'];
}
$startRow_Recordset2 = $pageNum_Recordset2 * $maxRows_Recordset2;

mysql_select_db($database, $con);
$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT * FROM database1 
                       JOIN users USING (userID)
                       JOIN table1 ON table1.myID=table2.myID 
                       JOIN table4 ON table4.alias=table2.product 
                       JOIN table5 USING (table5ID) 
                     WHERE TO_DAYS(added)=TO_DAYS(NOW()) 
                       AND userID = '300' 
                       AND table5ID='1' 
                       AND mode IN ('sent', 'success')";
$query_limit_Recordset2 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_Recordset2, $startRow_Recordset2, $maxRows_Recordset2);
$Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_limit_Recordset2, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_Recordset2'])) {
    $totalRows_Recordset2 = $_GET['totalRows_Recordset2'];
} else {
    $all_Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2);
    $totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($all_Recordset2);
}
$totalPages_Recordset2 = ceil($totalRows_Recordset2/$maxRows_Recordset2)-1;

$queryString_Recordset2 = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $newParams = array();
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        if (stristr($param, "pageNum_Recordset2") == false && 
            stristr($param, "totalRows_Recordset2") == false) {
            array_push($newParams, $param);
        }
    }
    if (count($newParams) != 0) {
        $queryString_Recordset2 = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
    }
}
$queryString_Recordset2 = sprintf("&totalRows_Recordset2=%d%s", $totalRows_Recordset2, $queryString_Recordset2);

?>
```

Comment: I think you missed out part of the question. Please add the 2 queries to your question.

Comment: Okay. The first query queries all the data posted on that day while the second queries only data that was posted successfully.

Comment: I intend to combine the two recordsets into one html table using a do-while statement.

Comment: <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Today</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>Failed</td>
        <td>Successful</td>
      </tr>
      <?php do { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['table5ID']; ?></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><?php echo $totalRows_Recordset2; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while (($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) and ($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2))); ?>
    </table>

Comment: Maybe I am being a little simple here but like you say you have all the data returned in the first query, why not just change the second query into a `COUNT(*)` as you only seem to use the `$totalRows_Recordser2` as information.

Comment: I will pick other fields later from the second recordset so i don't need to limit it using a count. My problem though is with the combined html table because it only shows records from one recordset and not from both recordset.

Comment: The data returned in the resultset of both queries is exactly the same as far as I can see, except that you limit the second query to only those where mode = 'success' or 'sent'. Could you not just retrieve the first queries results into an array and then process that however you want. That way if you need to jump about or re-process through it you can without the need for the second query.

Comment: Yes the two queries are almost similar. I need both of them however because i need to create a dynamic table that will 1. query all the data (recordset1). 2. Query data where the mode is only ('sent', 'success') I will the create dynamic fomulars to subtract the totalrows of recordset2 from those of recordset1 so that i can echo them in the column failed. In other words i will have the total count (which will be the result of recordset1, successes (which will be the count of recordset2 and failures which will be a subtraction of the two results. That's why i need both queries.

Comment: What @RiggsFolly is saying is: is there another `mode` different of `('sent', 'success')` ? If your answer is NO then he is tottaly right you don't need both queries they are the same. You just need to use the recordSet back and foward to use the data.